# ListFragment custom font

Tags: listview, fragment, typeface

I have created a ListFragment which works perfectly, I can change the background color of the listview, but I'm not able to change the typeface of the items in the list. How could I do this?

This is my listfragment.java :

```
public class Opciones extends ListFragment {

 private String myfriends[];
  private String sexo;
  LinearLayout layoutopciones;
  View view;
 public Opciones() {

  myfriends = new String[] {
    "Modificar datos perfil", 
    "Borrar perfil",
    "Borrar progreso ejercicios",
    "Opcion",
    "Opcion", 
    "Opcion",
  };
 }


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




 ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myfriends);
  setListAdapter(listAdapter); 
 } 

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentopciones, container, false);

  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentopciones, container, false);

 }
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        sexo=   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyData();
          layoutopciones=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layoutopciones);
          if(sexo.equals("mujer")){    
                 layoutopciones.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E37AA9"));
             }  
    }}
```

This is fragmentopciones.xml :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/layoutopciones"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#56B6C3"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp" >

 <ListView
android:id="@id/android:list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >

 </ListView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an incredible pain in the ass to do, and really shouldn't be.  Here's what I had to do.

1) Create a custom class to handle loading the custom typeface.  However, this has serious memory leak issues, and you have to avoid those.  I followed the code here in #7: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

Note that you must include the path to your font like this: "fonts/your_font.ttf"

2) Create a custom adapter to allow you to access the custom typeface class.  See here: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

3) Change your `new ArrayAdapter` bit to reference the custom adapter.